# Exclude results from MySQL query if customer already present in same table albeit fulfilling different criteria

Tags: mysql, e-commerce

I have an abandoned cart query in order to create a mailing list. One thing I don't want to do is e-mail anybody who has made an order past their abandoned cart date, how would I go about adding that to the below:

```
select *
from cart
where order_status = ''
and date_ordered = '0000-00-00'
and customer_email IS NOT NULL
and date_added > subdate(current_date, 1)
and date_added < current_date
and brand Is Not Null
and customer_email != ' '
group by customer
order by date_added desc;
```

So now I'd like to exclude records where the customer ID is present against an order in the same day. So as not to e-mail them the next day if they have made an order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join against the table containing the orders (assuming the cart again here) on the email address and for a different order (assuming order_id to check this part) and check for a NULL

```
select a.*
from cart a
LEFT OUTER JOIN cart b
ON a.customer_email = b.customer_email AND a.order_id != b.order_id
where a.order_status = ''
and a.date_ordered = '0000-00-00'
and a.customer_email IS NOT NULL
and a.date_added > subdate(current_date, 1)
and a.date_added < current_date
and a.brand Is Not Null
and a.customer_email != ' '
AND b.customer_email IS NULL
group by a.customer
order by a.date_added desc;
```

Comment: Hi there, this is certainly going in the right direction. I'm confused as to why I want to look for a Null in customer_email. I actually just want to exclude the row if there is another order WITH an order date after yesterday/today. I think I probably explained it poorly.

Comment: That is what it does. It does a LEFT JOIN so it will get a row whether there is a matching record or not. Then by checking for NULL in one of the fields from the LEFT JOINed table it is excluding those where it does have a match

Comment: And so it does... Many apologies, I was cross-referencing my results incorrectly - both people in original query returned to order and neither have showed up in your version, thanks so much for your help. Also you have done an immaculate job of copying the query structure above, that helps A LOT!!!